# Как установить высоту TextField KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Именно не максимальную высоту, а изначальную. То есть, насколько большим будет поле ввода по-умолчанию?

Так с шириной не работает:

```
MDTextField:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 120
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по [документации](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126171803/https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/text-field/index.html#maximum-height), высота задается через *height* как строка, например:

```
height: "30dp"
```

То же и для максимальной высоты:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen

    MDTextField:
        size_hint_x: .5
        hint_text: "multiline=True"
        max_height: "200dp"
        mode: "fill"
        fill_color: 0, 0, 0, .4
        multiline: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Comment: Довольно пустой и непонятный ответ